# Code First Link Table syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 models in my code such that
Model 1 has a property called Id
Model 2 has a property called ModuleId

The database contains 2 tables with those appropriate fields in them

I also have a link table (Modules_And_Questions) in the database defined as;

```
    Id [int]
    ModuleId [int]
    QuestionId [int]
```

In my context constructor I have the following code to link the 2 models together;

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Module>().HasMany(m => m.Questions).WithMany()
          .Map(
            q =>
            {
                q.ToTable("Modules_And_Questions");
                q.MapLeftKey("ModuleId");
                q.MapRightKey("Id");
            });

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

When I run the code to pull data from the tables, adn then attempt to use the object it complains. Looking into the sql of foo, it contains the line

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[ModuleId] = [Join1].[ModuleId]
```

manually editing this line so that [Extent1].[ModuleId] says [Extent1].[Id] means that the sql validates. So what do I need to change in my code or mapping to fix this issue, so that the generated sql is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What about to make a composit key for link table?

```
 public class  Modules_And_Questions
 {
   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public int ModuleId {get;set;}
   public Module Module {get;set;}
   [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
   public int QuestionId {get;set;}
   public Question ForeignKeyQuestion{get;set;}
 }


  modelBuilder.Entity<Modules_And_Questions>().HasRequired(m => m.Question).WithForeignKey(n=>n.QuestionId)
  modelBuilder.Entity<Modules_And_Questions>().HasRequired(m => m.Module).WithForeignKey(n=>n.ModuleId)
```

Comment: I can try that. But I thought (dangerous I know) that I didn't need to create an object for mapping tables ?

Comment: You doesn't need to load link type object. Compisite key will just provide to restrict unique relation beetween two entities.

Comment: Does not like the .WithForeignKey() part of the statements. Not sure if this is an EF version problem, but a google for ".WithForeignKey doesnt turn up too much